# Crontab - differences between *, */1 and 0-59/1

Tags: linux, cron

Ensuring it needs to run every minute, what is the difference between these three commands?

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/glpi/front/cron.php --force mailgate

*/1 * * * * php /var/www/html/glpi/front/cron.php --force mailgate

0-59/1 * * * * php /var/www/html/glpi/front/cron.php --force mailgate
```

Did the crontab run them differently or they are considered the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those three crontab schedule expressions are all equivalent.

`*` indicates "run every minute"

`*/1` indicates "every minute that is divisible by 1" (so, every minute).  Something like `*/2` would run every other minute.

`0-59/1` indicates "at every minute from 0 to 59 that is divisible by 1, run.  It's the same as `0-59`.

https://crontab.guru/ is pretty great for translating crontab schedule expressions to plain English.

Comment: oh, thanks for the help! i thought they would had some minor differences, but if crontab see they on the same way, it is a lot easier.

Comment: plue-uno for `crontab.guru`! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Heng : As a maintenance issue, it makes sense to standarize all entries on the simiplest statement that produces the correct result. Whoever put those in there wasted your time, don't pass it on to others in the future ;-) ! Good luck.